# Генерация случайного пути

Tags: алгоритм, математика, графика

Подскажите функцию для генерации случайной плавной кривой (например, как на картинке). 
Либо алгоритм построения такой функции `F(t)`, где `t` - динамический параметр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Бросьте несколько равноудалённых случайных точек на плоскость. Координата x у которых будет постоянно возрастать на шаг h, а высота будет случайным числом. Сами решите каким именно.
После этого аппроксимируйте это множество точек с помощью кубических сплайнов например.

Comment: А если, заранее не известно общее количество точек? И график должен строиться "в реальном времени"? Просто ожидал в ответе именно функцию с динамическими параметрами

Comment: Ну так и стройте график в реальном времени. А как добираетесь до последней точки, генерируйте ещё одну случайную - и стройте дальше. Ну или рисуйте "черепахой", плюс рандомное изменение направления движения (с неравномерной вероятностью выбора направления. чтобы не бродить по кругу) - тоже ничего.

Comment: На данный момент единственный вариант, который не приводит к y=f(x).

Comment: @Qwertiy, зато подходит, пусть и в некотором роде отвечает на вопрос не так, как нужно

Comment: @ThisMan, вообще-то я наоборот имел в виду, что это единственный вариант, отвечающий так как нужно. В вопросе `(x,y)=f(t)`, а у всех `y=f(x) & x=g(t)` :)

Answer (score 2):

Возьмите, так сказать, тренд :), что именно вам нужно - растущая, убывающая, колеблющаяся около нуля - и на каждом небольшом шагу *решения соответствующего дифуравнения* тем же простейшим Эйлером добавьте случайные отклонения. Такое сойдет? Вот такая испорченная синусоида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот соответствующий код:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    default_random_engine u;
    normal_distribution<double> rnd(0.0,0.1);

    double y = 0.0;
    double h = 0.1;
    for(double x = 0.0; x < 10.0; x += h)
    {
        y += cos(x)*h + rnd(u);
        cout << "{" << x << "," << y << "},\n";
    }
}
```

(он у меня данные для Wolfram Mathematica выводит). Гладкость и прочее - подбирается параметрами...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поэкспериментировал с многочленами. Контролировал бы определенным образом коэффициенты. Зависимость коэффициентов уже зависит конкретно от вашей задачи (какие ограничения должны быть наложены)

Comment: С одной стороны на ответ не тянет, с другой -- топикстартер просит алгоритм... ладно, нормально выглядит.

Comment: @AK, да, согласен. Если автор дал бы более конкретные ограничения на функцию, я бы конкретизировал бы ответ